# Сдвиг числа в ассемблере командой RCR

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Задание:
Реализовать в С++ функцию void BigRorCount(byte* M1, short len, short count), где M1 – сверхбольшое целое положительное число (байтовый массив длиною len), count – количество разрядов сдвига. Операция – циклический сдвиг вправо (в сторону младших разрядов) на количество двоичных разрядов, заданное параметром count. При этом count младших  разрядов уступают на место старших разрядов . Нужно использовать команды для 32-разрядных данных. Если значения len не кратно 4, то при необходимости для последних байт использовать команды для 8-разрядных данных.

Суть проблемы:
не переносит последний бит на перед

Source.cpp:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define n 8 // количество байтов у сверхбольшому числе

typedef unsigned char byte; 

extern "C" void BigRorCount(byte* M1, short len, short count);

void PrintBinary(byte *number, short length)
{
    for (short i = length; i != 0; --i)
    {
        byte currentPart = *(number + i - 1);
        currentPart & 0x80 ? printf("1") : printf("0");
        currentPart & 0x40 ? printf("1") : printf("0");
        currentPart & 0x20 ? printf("1") : printf("0");
        currentPart & 0x10 ? printf("1") : printf("0");
        currentPart & 0x08 ? printf("1") : printf("0");
        currentPart & 0x04 ? printf("1") : printf("0");
        currentPart & 0x02 ? printf("1") : printf("0");
        currentPart & 0x01 ? printf("1") : printf("0");
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    byte x[n];//сверхбольшое число
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = rand() % 255;
    }
    printf("Before: \n\n");
    printf("M1 = \n");
    PrintBinary(x, n);
    BigRorCount(x, n, 1);
    printf("New M1 = \n");
    PrintBinary(x, n);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}`
```

AsmSource.asm:

```
    .386
    .model flat, C

    .code
    BigRorCount proc

    push ebp
        mov ebp, esp;

        mov edi, [ebp + 8]  ;m1
        mov ebx, [ebp + 12] ;length
        mov esi, [ebp + 14] ; count

        cmp dl, 0
        je false
        true: 
        mov al, 1
        jmp cont
        false:
        mov al, 0
        cont:
        mov ecx, 0
        clc 
        pushf


        _loop:
        cmp ecx, ebx
        jge finish
        popf
        rcr byte ptr[edi+ecx], 1
        pushf
        inc ecx
        jmp _loop


 ;;;;;;;;;;;
         pushf
        rcl byte ptr[edi+0], 1
        popf
        rcr byte ptr[edi+0], 1
 ;;;;;;;;;;;

; _while:
;   cmp eax, esi
;   jge finish
;   mov ecx,0
;       _loop:
;           cmp ecx, ebx
;           jge label1
;            popf
;            rcr byte ptr[edi+ecx],1
;            pushf
;            inc ecx
;            jmp _loop
; label1:
; inc eax
; jmp _while
; попытка реализации сдвига через двойной цикл
    finish:
    popf

    pop ebp
    ret

BigRorCount endp
end
```

Comment: когда вы двигаете первый байт в массиве, то в старший разряд вдвигается 0 (т.к. вы предварительно выполняли clc). Так что могу предложить после завершения цикла сохранить флаги (в переносе будет выдвинутый из последнего байта бит), взять опять первый байт, вернуть его биты на место (например rcl X, 1), восстановить флаги и сделать rcr X,1 т.е. вдвинуть сохраненный бит в начало первого байта

Comment: У вас та часть, которая выделена точками с запятой никогда не выполняется, потому что прямо перед ней стоит безусловный jmp. эта часть должна быть в точке finish. и pushf в ее начале делать не надо, т.к. pushf уже сделан внутри цикла

Comment: Оно просто обязано работать. у вас в точке finish вместо popf теперь rcl / popf / rcr ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/69bQzpHJ вот код еще раз

Comment: Почему это, я же уже обратил ваше внимание на то, что вы байты печатаете на экране не в том порядке, в каком сдвигаете. И первая единица в первый байт на экране абсолютно логично пришла из второго байта на экране. А вот последний ноль из первого байта вы перенесли в начало третьего на экране (0-го в массиве) байта

Comment: Я наконец-то понял, в чем была ошибка, которую я по факту пропускал мимо ушей, хотя вы говорили. Спасибо. А еще я хотел бы уточнить как именно для length кратно 4 правильно делать сдвиг используя  команды для 32-разрядных данных. Вот что я прикинул  https://pastebin.com/2Gga9fuP но сдвиг опять ломается

Comment: Там что то странное. вы проверяете остаток от деления на 4 (который кстати равен младшим 2м битам числа) И если он не ноль вы всю строку целиком сдвигаете по 1 байту, вместо того, что бы сдвигать только те несколько раз. Вам надо просто сделать `mov edx, ebx  /  and edx, 3` и выполнять сдвиг по 1 байту только это кол-во раз (пока ecx не достигнет edx) (ну или конца строки, если на короче), после этого никаких финишных действий не надо, сразу переходите к сдвигу 32-бита. когда 32-битный блок закончился, делаете финишную часть.

Comment: А если предположить, что начало массива выравнено на 4 байта, то более эффективным будет сначала двигать по 32 бита, пока ebx-ecx>3, а потом двигать оставшиеся насколько байт. для быстрой проверки ebx-ecx>3 стоит заранее вычесть из ebx младшие 2 бита. И кстати, самое главное забыл, вы когда по 32 бита двигаете, вы ecx то на 4 увеличивайте, а не на 1

Comment: @Mike Если честно, я не совсем понял, то что вы расписали. Не могли бы ли вы, когда будет свободное время приблизительно отредактировать код, согласно вашим заметкам?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70469/discussion-on-question-by-sasha-urban------rcr).

Comment: @Mike, а может, ответы - в ответы?

Comment: @SashaUrban Я все таки думаю, вы не с того конца двигаете. от конца массива к началу (с ecx=ebx до 0 делая dec ecx) будет более логично. И главное, у вас сейчас 32 битный сдвиг и 8 битный в любом случае дадут разный результат. потому что в 32 битах байты лежать как раз задом наперед. Если идти с хвоста, то все встает на свои места, включая тот последний бит и все становится гораздо проще, первых блок копирует 32 бита, делая sub ecx, 4 до тех пор пока ecx>3, потом побайтно уменьшаете до 0 во втором блоке